# How to fix decorator mock

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, decorator

I have a problem with mocking my decorator in my flask app.
I've tried monkeypatch, mock.patch  and none is working

I'm running with python3.7

Here is my code 
in => app/v1/views/user_data.py

```py
@r.route('/myroute/<int:user_id>', methods=['GET'])
@verify_token
def ep_intern_midas_user_data_user_id(user_id):
    # do some stuff here
    return "Done"
```

in app/v1/decorators/verify_token.py

```py
def verify_token(view_function):
    @wraps(view_function)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        # do decorator stuff

   return decorated_function
```

in tests/unit_tests/views/user_data.py

```py
from functools import wraps
from app.v1 import decorators

def mock_decorator():
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            return 200
        return decorated_function
    return decorator
# !important thing - import of app after replace
decorators.verify_token = mock_decorator

from app import app
app.testing = True

def test_index():
    with app.test_client() as client:
        res = client.get('v1/intern/midas/user_data/1')
        assert res.status_code == 200



(even with monkeypatch) 
===== never works
```

I expected to have the result 200 but I have 401, what is the result if the decorator is called and not its mock.

Thanks for help